# Align End Of Line Comments in Vim?

Tags: vim, formatting, comments

Inside Vim, is there a formatting command that would align a block of end of line comments?

For example in C++, it would turn this:

```
m_varName1;   // Comment 1
m_varName1AndABit;       // Command 1 and a bit
m_varName2;     // Comment 2
m_varName3ButReally2AndABit;   // Comment 3 (but really 2 and a bit)
```

into this:

```
m_varName1;                   // Comment 1
m_varName1AndABit;            // Command 1 and a bit
m_varName2;                   // Comment 2
m_varName3ButReally2AndABit;  // Comment 3 (but really 2 and a bit)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [`tabular.vim`](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) plugin should be able to do this.  Select them visually, and align them with

```
:Tabularize /\/\/
```

Comment: Actually you don't need to select visually, unless you want more precision. Tabularize is smart enough to detect a block. Also, you may find `:Tab` easier to use.

Comment: After trying Align I went with Tabularize based on a personal preference.  Both solved the problem but Tabularize seems a cleaner solution to me.

Comment: how do you interpret "/\/\/" ?

Comment: @JihoNoh `/\/\/` is the search/match expression for the comment characters `//`. Tabularize accepts a vim search, such as you might search for it with the `/` command and backslash-escape the two `//` each as `\/`

Comment: Any ideas on how to do it without plugins?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [Align](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294) plugin for Vim to align based on whatever separator(s) you choose.

Comment: At first I was all for it, but Align has a couple of side effect - one of which was conflicting with my existing key maps.

Comment: you can remap the key maps.  I don't use them at all.  I just use `:Align <separator>`

Comment: True but I don't have that problem 'out of the box' with Tabularize so it wins.  But this goes to a larger discussion outside of this question about how to design a vim plugin.