# vim Aligning inline comments

Tags: vim

Not really sure how to phrase this other than by example..

Given...

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',    # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
    'NAME': 'adroit',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
    'USER': 'root',                    # Not used with sqlite3.
    'PASSWORD': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
    'HOST': '',                         # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
    'PORT': '',                            # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
}
```

}

How would I format it so that all of the comments line up correctly, like so

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',  # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
    'NAME': 'adroit',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
    'USER': 'root',                        # Not used with sqlite3.
    'PASSWORD': '',                        # Not used with sqlite3.
    'HOST': '',                            # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
    'PORT': '',                            # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
}
```

}

The above example is from a django settings file, but I come across this issue a lot in various languages so ideally I would be looking for a way of doing this regardless of the comment delimiter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Align End Of Line Comments in Vim?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248621/align-end-of-line-comments-in-vim)

Comment: See linked question, though in your case the expression to align them is `:Tabularize /#`

Comment: I saw the first part and thought I should edit this question by lining up the comments =P.

Comment: Wow, I never realized how badly I needed this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular). With this plugin you can just visually select the part you want to align and then type:

```
'<,'>Tabularize /#
```

It works so nicely that it looks like magic.

Comment: Are there any instructions on how to install the plugin? Simply copying the files causes errors on load for me.

Comment: @FergalMoran I know. It's great.

Comment: @puk The github repo is tricky to install. I downloaded it from here http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3464

Comment: @FergalMoran that looks almost identical. I am copying it to `.vim/bundles` and I keep getting the same error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9843648/cant-install-vim-tabular-plugin/9846275#9846275

Comment: @puk download it to your ~/.vim/plugins directory

Comment: @FergalMoran are you sure you don't mean the `~/vim/plugin` directory (Without the `s`)? I don't have a `plugins` directory. If I create one, nothing happens. In my `~/vim/plugin` directory everything is a `.vim` file. Did you provide me the wrong download link perhaps?

Comment: @FergalMoran Well I'll be, it actually worked when I put it in the `~/vim/plugin` directory. Thank you