# Can't install vim Tabular Plugin

Tags: vim, plugins

There are no installation instructions for the [tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) plugin. I tried either copying the files into the correct folders, or putting in under `~/.vim/bundle` to let pathogen deal with it, in both cases I get the following error messages when I load up vim (if it's of any concern, the message is repeated 6 times).

> AddTabularPattern: Vim(runtime):E194: No alternate file name to substitute for '#': runtime autoload/tabular#ElementFormatPattern.vim

---

**EDIT** some more information if it will help diagnose the problem

Here is where the files are stored in my `~/.vim/bundles/godlygeek-tabular-b7b4d87` folder (not I obviously have not shown **all** files)

```
.vim/
├── [drwxrwxr-x]  bundle
│   ├── [drwxrwxr-x]  godlygeek-tabular-b7b4d87
│   │   ├── [drwxrwxr-x]  after
│   │   │   └── [drwxrwxr-x]  plugin
│   │   │       └── [-rw-rw-r--]  TabularMaps.vim
│   │   ├── [drwxrwxr-x]  autoload
│   │   │   └── [-rw-rw-r--]  tabular.vim
│   │   ├── [drwxrwxr-x]  doc
│   │   │   └── [-rw-rw-r--]  Tabular.txt
│   │   └── [drwxrwxr-x]  plugin
│   │       └── [-rw-rw-r--]  Tabular.vim
```

Comment: NOTE: I found a solution here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9843019/654789

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you tell us a bit more about your setup? With a diagram if possible?

The `AddTabularPattern` command is called exactly 6 times from `after/plugin/TabularMaps.vim` and declared in `plugin/Tabular.vim`. I don't see why it would trigger the expansion of `#`, though.

Comment: Was that diagram comment tongue-in-cheek? If not, could you explain what you want (with a diagram if possible)

Comment: I added information on my `~/vim/` folder. Let me know if you want me to post something else.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. My comment was not tongue-in-cheek at all, I just wanted to check out if something was missing or misplaced.

Comment: I'd be glad to provide a diagram, I just don't know what you'd like me to put in it b/c "diagrams" are generally used to present visual data (ie. information flow)

Comment: I found a solution in the comments section of another question http://stackoverflow.com/a/9843019/654789

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, Tabular comes with an after directory which contains a plugin in its own directory, an autoload directory, a doc directory & a plugin directory.

So just copy the contents of those directories to their counterparts in $HOME/.vim/ (making any directory that does not already exist) & you're good to go.

Comment: Same problem on a Windows machine. @phildobbin's solution worked for me:
```.../vim74/
├───plugin
│   └───tabular
│       ├───.git
│       │   ├───branches
│       │   ├───hooks
│       │   ├───info
│       │   ├───logs
│       │   │   └───refs
│       │   │       └───heads
│       │   ├───objects
│       │   │   ├───info
│       │   │   └───pack
│       │   └───refs
│       │       ├───heads
│       │       ├───remotes
│       │       │   └───origin
│       │       └───tags
│       ├───after
│       │   └───plugin
│       ├───autoload
│       ├───doc
│       └───plugin
└───syntax```

Comment: I still can't format the mini-markdown right.  Ask me if you need more clarification.  I posted my tree here: [http://fpaste.org/130152/](http://fpaste.org/130152/).

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this does not answer your question directly (I could not replicate the error), but you could try using [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle) to manage your Vim plugins. It serves a very similar purpose as pathogen, but with one important difference: it's entirely declarative.

If you used Vundle, installing Tabular would require you only to put this line into your .vimrc:

```
Bundle 'Tabular'
```

and then issue `:BundleInstall` command and that's it.

It also supports downloading the plugins from GitHub, so alternatively you could use:

```
Bundle 'godlygeek/tabular'
```

I have switched from pathogen to Vundle a while ago and haven't looked back.

Comment: I will have a look at it sometime in the future, but right now I can't drop everything else I'm learning in exchange for this. Thank you nevertheless.