# How to improve this vim mapping to format/align similar lines

Tags: vim

Recently I was in need of a faster way to format similar code lines according a common character (usually `=`). For example, I want to format this:

```
myVar = getMyVar();
myLongerVar = getMyLongerVar();
myYetLongerVar = getMyYetLongerVar();
```

into that:

```
myVar          = getMyVar();
myLongerVar    = getMyLongerVar();
myYetLongerVar = getMyYetLongerVar();
```

then I wrote the following mappings:

```
" query used to find the common character. In this case i'm setting it to "find the ="
let g:defformatquery = "f="

" set current line as having the longer size till the common character
nnoremap <Leader>gm 0
            \:execute "normal " . g:defformatquery<CR>
            \:let b:epos = getpos(".")[2]<CR>

" format current line according to the position acquired above
nnoremap <Leader>g= 0
            \:execute "normal " . g:defformatquery<CR>hvgeld
            \:execute "normal " . (b:epos - getpos(".")[2]) . "i "<CR>
```

To use them I have to perform these steps (assuming `,` is my `<Leader>`):

1. position the cursor in the line with the longer text before the `=` sign (the third line in the example provided, `myYetLongerVar`)
2. press: `,gm`
3. for each line I want to format, position the cursor there and press `,g=`

Although this works, the process is kinda slow.
I want to create a function that would format the entire selected area at once. Then I could just create one map for the function.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you aware of tabular.vim? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8964953/align-text-on-an-equal-sign-with-vim/8964979#8964979 , also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248621/align-end-of-line-comments-in-vim/7248713#7248713

Comment: @Michael very nice! I think that plugin solves my question :)

Comment: For small yet relatively universal alignment tricks that work without plugins, see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7538363/254635) to the question "[Inserting indentation for columns in Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7529029/254635)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the [Align plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294).

For example, to align some selected lines (selected with <kbd>v</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL-v</kbd>) according to the `=` sign, you just type:

```
:Align =
```

Or to align from line 34 to 39:

```
:34,39Align =
```