# VIM array format

Tags: vim

Is there a way in VIM to format an array in a way the space between the key and the value is always the same?

Like from this format :

```
$array = array(
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2',
    '3' => 'value3',
    'thisis4' => 'value 4!'
);
```

To the following :

```
$array = array(
    'key1'       =>    'value1',
    'key2'       =>    'value2',
    '3'          =>    'value3',
    'thisis4'    =>    'value 4!'
);
```

In the example I used a PHP syntax, but the question is not PHP related.

Comment: Probably using tabular.vim https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248621/align-end-of-line-comments-in-vim/7248713#7248713  I guess I don't have it installed right now to verify it will work with the `=>` delimiter, but I expect it will.

Comment: Or install vim-phpfmt